# How to redirect php page using ajax with data?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I know there are lots of questions here with the same title as mine but I can't solve my problem using the answers provided for them.
The program is supposed to redirect the page to the OCR result after taking a screenshot of the google map. What happen is that I can only see the result through network > proceessing.php > preview.
I also tried to use `window.location.href = "your-url-to-redirect-to";` on the ajax but it would only cause the page a lot of errors for missing data.
Below is the index.php

```
<body>
<input type='button' class="btn btn-success" id='but_screenshot' value='Take screenshot' onclick='screenshot();'><br/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function screenshot() {
        var transform = $(".gm-style>div:first>div:first>div:last>div").css("transform");
        var comp = transform.split(",")
        var mapleft = parseFloat(comp[4])
        var maptop = parseFloat(comp[5])
        $(".gm-style>div:first>div:first>div:last>div").css({ 
            "transform":"none",
            "left":mapleft,
            "top":maptop,
        });
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('map'), {
            useCORS: true
        }).
        then(function(canvas) {
                var base64URL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').replace('image/jpeg', 'image/octet-stream');
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'processing.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {image: base64URL},
                    success: function(data){
                        console.log('Upload successfully');
                    }
                });
            }
        );
    }
</script>
</body>
```

This is the `processing.php`

```
<?php
// upload screenshot
$image = $_POST['image'];
$location = "uploads/";
$image_parts = explode(";base64,", $image);
$image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
$filename = "screenshot_".uniqid().'.png';
$file = $location . $filename;

file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);
// end

uploadToApi($file);

function uploadToApi($target_file){
    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    $fileData = fopen($target_file, 'r');
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    try {
    $r = $client->request('POST', 'https://api.ocr.space/parse/image',[
        'headers' => ['apiKey' => '[API_KEY]'],
        'multipart' => [
            [
                'name' => 'file',
                'contents' => $fileData
            ]
        ]
    ], ['file' => $fileData]);
    $response =  json_decode($r->getBody(),true);
    if(empty($response['ErrorMessage'])) {
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Result</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="form-group container">
            <label for="exampleTextarea">Result</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="30">
            <?php
                foreach($response['ParsedResults'] as $pareValue) {
                    echo $pareValue['ParsedText'];
                }
            ?></textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    } else {
        header('HTTP/1.0 400 Forbidden');
        echo $response['ErrorMessage'];
    }
    } catch(Exception $err) {
        header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
        echo $err->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: header php function must be called before any actual output is sent [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: you know that ajax is there to avoid the need to redirect to the php page do you?

Comment: `window.location.href` should work, what was the value you tried, maybe you added wrong redirect URL, `window.location.href` should have full URL including the domain name and the path you want to redirect the user to.

Comment: @mamounothman I tried to redirect `processing.php`

Comment: @LelioFaieta no I didn't know that. I'm new to programming and that is a sample code I just downloaded for testing

Comment: instead of using ajax just use a form with hidden inputs and you submit it. You are redircted to the php page and can see the output. Ajax is if you want to see the result updated inside the page you are calling from

Comment: @newbie it should be `window.location.href = 'http://SITE_URL/PATH/'+processing.php` but I agree with @LelioFaieta though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order not to change everything, you can simply return from processing.php only:

```
<div class="form-group container">
        <label for="exampleTextarea">Result</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleTextarea" rows="30">
        <?php
            foreach($response['ParsedResults'] as $pareValue) {
                echo $pareValue['ParsedText'];
            }
        ?></textarea>
    </div>
```

and then in the index.php in the

```
success: function (data) {
        document.getElementById("Any div").innerHTML + = data
    // or to body
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + data;
    }
```

These must be included in index.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```